# Scroller events don't fire in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, dom-events

I configured scroll events in a dataview but they don't fire. The rest of scrollable configuration is OK, just the listeners conf doesn't seem to be considered. Any clue ?

```
{   itemId:'names',
    xtype:'dataview',
    disableSelection:true,
    scrollable:{
        direction:'vertical',
        listeners:{
            scroll:function(){
                console.log('[scrollable][on scroll]');
            },
            scrollend:function( scroller, x, y, eOpts ){
                console.log('[scrollable][on scrollend]x='+x+', y='+y);
            }
        }
    },
    store:{
            fields:['name'],
            data:[{name:'Cherif'}]
    },

    itemTpl:'{name}'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit: Actually tried suggested fix out this time**

You need to put the `listeners` config inside a `scroller` as [demonstrated in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxUDs/1/):

```
{
    xtype:'dataview',
    fullscreen: true,
    scrollable: {
        direction:'vertical',
        scroller: {
            listeners:{
                scroll:function(){
                    console.log('[scrollable][on scroll]');
                },
                scrollend:function( scroller, x, y, eOpts ){
                    console.log('[scrollable][on scrollend]x='+x+', y='+y);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'age'],
        data: [
            {name: 'Jamie',  age: 100},
            {name: 'Rob',   age: 21},
            {name: 'Tommy', age: 24},
            {name: 'Jacky', age: 24},
            {name: 'Ed',   age: 26}
        ]
    },

    itemTpl: '<div>{name} is {age} years old</div>'
}
```

Comment: @Cherif trying to set listeners for scroller not for dataview. Also there is no scroll or scrollend event for dataview.. did you noted that ?